# R and Mapview: How can I chose different colors for different layers?

Tags: r, mapping

Here is an example:

```r
library(sf)
library(mapview)

data(meuse)

d <- st_as_sf(meuse, coords = c("x", "y"))
d1 <- d[sample(nrow(d), 20), ]
d2 <- d[sample(nrow(d), 20), ]

mapview(list(d1, d2))
```

Both layers, `d1` and `d2`, and displayed using the same color. How can I chose different colors, say red for `d1` and blue for `d2`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to add arguments for colors, see `?mapview`. In your case for main color you can use `col.regions=list("red","blue")` and `col=list("red","blue")` for outlines. So whole code could be like this:

```
library(sp)
library(sf)
library(mapview)

data(meuse)

d <- st_as_sf(meuse,coords =  c("x","y"))
d1 <- d[sample(nrow(d),20),]
d2 <- d[sample(nrow(d),20),]

mapview(list(d1,d2),col.regions=list("red","blue"),col=list("red","blue"))
```

Comment: Or use `+` to concatenate the 2 layers: `mapview(d1, col.regions = "red") + mapview(d2, col.regions = "blue")`

Comment: Great, thanks! What I tried before was col.regions=c("red","blue"),col=c("red","blue")... which didn't work. It seems to make a difference if you provide lists or vectors as arguments to col.regions. Thanks!

Comment: I feel like it shouldn't make a difference, but to be honest, the list method of mapview has become my personal nemesis! I am the mapview developer BTW. If you feel strongly about this, please open an issue on the mapview github repo.